# How to decode ShredStream data of Jito?

Tags: rpc, node

```
Shredstream provides the lowest latency shreds to any RPC or validator on the network
```

This is what it says on Shredstream page, and here is what I do:

```
 1 RUST_LOG=info cargo run --release --bin jito-shredstream-proxy -- shredstream \
  2     --block-engine-url https://ny.mainnet.block-engine.jito.wtf \
  3     --auth-keypair /home/sre/shredstream/shred-keypair.json \
  4     --desired-regions ny \
  5     --dest-ip-ports 127.0.0.1:18001 > shred_log.txt 2>&1
```

I watch 127.0.0.1:18001 and get data from it, but I dont know how to decode that, any one have idea about that?
Or maybe I should change 127.0.0.1:18001 to 127.0.0.1:8001(my local solana rpc node), and then get shredstream data from rpc websoket api? like **onprogramsubscribe**?

I am now to solana and jito, appreciate for any help